# How to get a list of highest-voted answers?

Tags: support, answers, search, vote-count

I can sort the list of questions based on the number of votes and on tags.
Can I do the same thing for answers?

Comment: Where exactly do you get a list of answers only that are not attached to questions?

Comment: What question? I'm talking about the sorted list of answers bases on vote and tags, the kind of question is not important.

Comment: Well, you say "list of questions" and the talk about same thing for "answers". I was wondering what list of answers. I don't believe you can just get a list of answers - only lists of answers that are to a particular question.

Comment: @Downvoter Why downvote?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [advanced search option](https://stackoverflow.com/search) (expand tips) `is:answer` to narrow your search.

For example, here's [the highest voted WPF answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is:answer%20%5Bwpf%5D).

Some of the other [ninja search options](https://stackoverflow.com/search#advanced-search) will also produce results with questions and answers:

- [code:INotify](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code:INotify)
- [user:me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame&submit=search)
- [url:"http://jsfiddle.net/*"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22http://jsfiddle.net/*%22)